# Calculating the Number of Pairs of elements in a List that produce a Sum divisible by 60 - reduce the Time Complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, big-o, combinations

There are many permutation optimization questions, but every one is different.

At a coding assignment recently, I was asked, given a list of numbers, to find how many pairs add up to a multiple of 60.

I've come up with was the following solution:

```java
public int getPairs(List<Integer> nums){
  int result = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
   for(int j=i+1; j<nums.size(); j++) {
     if((nums.get(i)+nums.get(j))%60 == 0){
       result++
     }
   }
  }
  return result; 
}
```

This code was correct, however the testing software failed some hidden test cases where the list of nums was 10000 because of "time out", meaning that it took too long.

I've tried converting the List to an array first, to save on `size()` and `get()` method calls, but it did not help me.

I am very confused. Is this not the fastest way to go over all possible combinations?

If the question asked not for a multiple of 60, but to be 60, then I would sort the array first, and as soon as the sum is greater then 60, skip over the rest of the array, but this is not the case.

Also, it's strange that 10000 size array should time out. 10,000 x 10,000 is 100,000,000. Surely doing an two additions, a division, compare, and and compareToZero 100,000,000 should take less than a second on a modern processor.

Did I do something wrong, or is the testing software bugged?

Comment: You thought of optimizations for asking "do they add up to 60". Replacing each entry in the array with its value mod 60 is a single non-nested loop. So if the optimization is sufficiently useful, then doing that preprocessing step would improve the overall runtime. Generally speaking these kinds of optimizations problems are NOT an excercise in "how do I execute the brute force attempt the fastest" but of "how do I avoid doing most of the work".

Comment: Another possible optimization: there are only 60 possible interesting values. In a single loop you can count how many values are 0 mod 60, 1 mod 60, 2 mod 60, ... 59 mod 60. Then in another simple loop you can calculate the result from that fixed-sized array.

Comment: I actually tried the first step also, and it didn't help me. The second one is very interesting.

Comment: In the first loop, you can test `i<nums.size()-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mistakes explained

> This code was correct, however the testing software failed some hidden test cases where the list of nums was 10000 because of "time out", meaning that it took too long.

I would not say that the code is correct (since there's a flaw in it), rather you had no opportunity to see it failing on a small input.

In the inner `for`-loop you're initializing the staring value of the index `j` to `i` - `int j = i`. Which means at the first iteration of the inner loop, you're adding an element to ***itself***: `nums.get(i) + nums.get(j)` and then checking whether it's divisible by `60`.

That's might lead to invalid results. Inner loop should start with `j = i + 1`. With this fix, you'll get a correct brute-force solution.

The second issue - **terminology**.

What your code is counting are **not** [*Permutations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), **but** [*Combinations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of pairs of elements (it's not an academical spreading of hairs, the result would be different).

As a simple illustration, suppose the input is `[1,2,3]`, and we need Combinations of pairs of elements that are divisible by `3`. There's only one Combination: `[1,2]`, but two Permutations: `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`.

Because in your brute-force solution `i < j` always holds true, it's not capable of generating Permutations (since it doesn't revisit the same indices in the inner loop it can only consider `[i,j]`, but not `[j,i]`), and it produces the number of Combinations.

Now when the problem statement is clarified: *"Find the number of Combinations pairs that are divisible by the given number"*, let's get to the actual solution.

## Solution

As *@Joachim Sauer* has pointed out in the comments, the first step in addressing this problem is to create an array of frequencies of array elements `% 60` (like in the first phase of the Counting sort algorithm).

Then we have two cases:

- When considering remainder from divisions by `60` in the union ranges `[1,29]∪[31,59]` we need to calculate a [*Cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of frequencies of the corresponding remainders and add it to the total. I.e. `frequency(1)xfrequency(59)`, `frequency(2)xfrequency(58)`, ... all the way up to `frequency(29)xfrequency(31)`. **Note** that we shouldn't touch `frequency(0)` and `frequency(30)` (they need to be treated separately), we should not double count the product, i.e. we should not consider reversed combinations like `frequency(59)xfrequency(1)`.
- Combinations `frequency(0)` and `frequency(30)` are a special case because we can combine them only with themselves. And for both cases, we need to calculate a *Binomial coefficient* according to the following formula:

[image: Binomial coefficient - n! / k! (n - k)!]

Where `n` is the number of frequencies (for `0` or for `30`), and `k` is the number of elements in the combination, which is always equal to `2`.

That's how the implementation might look like (*to simplify testing, divisor `60` is not hard-coded, but provided as a method parameter*):

```
public static long getPairCount(List<Integer> list, int divisor) {
    int[] freq = new int[divisor]; // frequencies of modulus of array elements
    for (int next : list) freq[next % divisor]++;
    
    long count = 0;
    for (int left = 1, right = divisor - 1; left < divisor / 2 + divisor % 2; left++, right--) {
        count += ((long) freq[left]) * freq[right]; // a cartesian product gives a number of ways to form a pair
    }
    // Special cases: remainder 0 and remainder divisor / 2 - now with dialing with pure Combinations
    // and instead Cartesian product a Binomial coefficient needs to be calculated
    if (freq[0] > 1) count += binomialCoefficient(freq[0], 2 );
    if (divisor % 2 == 0 && freq[divisor / 2] > 1) count += binomialCoefficient(divisor / 2, 2 ); // should be only considered if divisor is
    return count;
}

public static long binomialCoefficient(int n, int k) {
    
    return factorial(n) / (k * factorial(n - k));
}

public static long factorial(int num) {
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getPairCount(List.of(1, 2, 3), 3)); // [1, 2]
    System.out.println(getPairCount(List.of(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 7)); // [2, 5] x 2, [3, 4] x 2
    System.out.println(getPairCount(List.of(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 5)); // [2, 3] x 4, [1, 4] x 2
    System.out.println(getPairCount(List.of(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5), 5)); // [2, 3] x 4, [1, 4] x 2, [5, 5]
}
```

*Output:*

```
1   // [1, 2]
4   // [2, 5] x 2, [3, 4] x 2
6   // [2, 3] x 4, [1, 4] x 2
7   // [2, 3] x 4, [1, 4] x 2, [5, 5]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that explanation. A few mistakes I noticed:
1. I actually initialize `j` to `i+1`, so it never counts with itself
2. You have order of operations wrong, as I don't believe the multiplication in the divisor will take precedence, so you need parenthesis around  `2 * factorial(freq[0] - 2)`

Comment: @f.khantsis *I actually initialize `j` to `i+1`* - sorry but not - [proof](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74787272/1). It is the initial version of the question where `j=i`. I accidentally posted the **changed version** while fixing the formatting (*I've used this fixed brute-force code in testing*).

Comment: @f.khantsis *so you need parenthesis around 2 * factorial(freq[0] - 2)* - fair point, fixed that. I was writing the answer during the night, that and messed around with these things.

Comment: @f.khantsis I've spotted one more bug, the current version should be correct. I've also undone my changes to your code in the question.

Comment: @f.khantsis Not sure if I've managed to explain the logic well, so feel free ask for clarifications if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking for reduced time complexity. May be for a solution with O(n) time complexity instead of n squared. I did get this question in a recent interview but failed to complete it on time. Did work on the solution offline, which is given below.

```
import java.util.*;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = List.of(10,20,-30,10,40,30,10,0);
        
        System.out.println(checkSum(numbers, 20));
    }
    public static int checkSum(List<Integer> numbers, int targetMultiple) {

       /*The Map contains the num already seen in the list along 
       with how many times it was seen
       if targetMultiple is non 0 then we save the remainder instead of 
       num along with count seen.*/
       Map<Integer,Integer> diffMap = new HashMap<>();

        // sign does not matter as we are checking for multiples
        targetMultiple = Math.abs(targetMultiple);

        int total = 0;

        for (int num : numbers) {
         
            int remainder = targetMultiple != 0? num % targetMultiple : num;
            int diff = targetMultiple - remainder;
            int remainderDiff = remainder * -1;

            // check existence of possible sum satisfying the required condition

            // sum adding up to 0 is also a multiple 
            Integer negRemainderCount = diffMap.get(remainderDiff);
            if (negRemainderCount != null ) {
                total += negRemainderCount;
            } 

            // sum adding to target multiple. Avoid duplicate checks, for example
            //these will be same when targetMultiple is 0.
            if (diff != remainderDiff ) {
                Integer diffCount = diffMap.get(diff);
                if (diffCount != null ) {
                    total += diffCount;
                }
            }
            
            // store current remainder in map
            Integer remainderCount = diffMap.get(remainder);
            if (remainderCount != null) {
                diffMap.put(remainder, remainderCount + 1); 
            } else {
                diffMap.put(remainder, 1);  
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

get this code

```
 public static int getPairs(List<Integer> nums, int divisor) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        if (i == divisor) {
          result++;
        } else {
          int j = 60 - i;
          if (nums.contains(j)) {
            result++;
          }
        }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).